# DynamoDBMappingException: could not unconvert attribute, expected S in value

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on getting map type data stored in DynamoDB, the way I have tried so far:

- use **String getData()** in my POJO, however, there is an issue that DynamoDBMappingException: could not unconvert attribute.
- use **Map<String, Object> getData()** and annotated with @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MapConverter.class) to retrieve the data, and also wrote a converter for it. This method also throws Exception DynamoDBMappingException: could not unconvert attribute, expected S in value.
  **So my question is:**

1. is there a way to retrieve the standard JSON format data from DynamoDB by using mapper instead of DynamoJson without “N”, “S”, etc?
   For instance:

```
      "data": {
          "cId":"777",
          "cName":"NPR"
          "isOwner":true
      }
```

Once I get the standard JSON, I can use objectmapper to convert it to arbitrary data based on different use cases.
2. is it possible to use a map here? I found some folks create POJO for nested data, however, in my use case, the data fields vary from the different scenarios.
The converter I wrote:

```
    public class MapConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Map> {
    
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
        public MapConverter() {
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        }
    
        @Override
        public String convert(final Map map) {
            if (map == null) {
                return null;
            }
    
            try {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                log.error("Hit exception while trying to convert map. {}.", map, e);
                return null;
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public Map unconvert(String serializedMap) {
            if (serializedMap == null) {
                return null;
            }
    
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(serializedMap, Map.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Hit exception while trying to unconvert map. {}.", serializedMap, e);
                return null;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

The data in the DynamoDB is like this:

```
    {
      "data": {
        "M": {
          "cId": {
            "S": "777"
          },
          "cName": {
            "S": "NPR"
          },
          "isOwner": {
            "BOOL": true
          }
        }
      }  
    }
```

and it may also look like

```
    "data": {
        "M": {
          "globalEntityId": {
            "S": "234"
          },
          "providerMetadata": {
            "L": [
              {
                "M": {
                  "proj.123": {
                    "M": {
                      "entityId": {
                        "S": "s:123"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "PA": {
                    "M": {
                      "entityId": {
                        "S": "p:123"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hey Ekin I was a little confused by your question. Could you rephrase "I am working on getting map type data stored in DynamoDB" and replace the word getting with retrieving? 

Furthermore could you provide the value of the serializedMap variable before you hit the exception? You can get this by adding a break point in the unconvert method on this line in your debugger: `return objectMapper.readValue(serializedMap, Map.class);` That's what we'll need instead of the two data examples you provided.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply. From the above example, I assumed that `data` is a map stored in DynamoDB. (I am a newbie in this field). And I want to retrieve it with dynamodbmapper in a standard JSON format string. Currently, I was not able to debug it since it is running on the cloud desk, hope I could learn how to debug in the cloud desk quickly.

Comment: Yes, remote debugging is useful indeed. How ever if you debug it remotely you will end up suspending the java program and this kind of temporary downtime while you inspect what is happening can be unwanted.  You would want to start the java program like this: `java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n` 
and then you can connect on port 8000 given that you only allow your IP to connect to this instance on port 8000 otherwise you have a huge security risk since anyone from the internet can attach a debugger and access sensitive data or run malicious code.

Comment: you should instead try to reproduce it on your computer, even copying an example data from the dynamodb to a development database if necessary